# Cats ValidatedNec mapN with Case Class Error Types

Tags: scala, validation, scala-cats, applicative

I'd like to use the Cats `ValidatedNec` data type similarly to the example in the Cats documentation for `Validated` in the section [Meeting applicative](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html#meeting-applicative)-- in my case, I'm parsing `String`s from a file, validating against an appropriate regex for the field, and then (for several fields) converting to a different data type (assuming the regex matched).  However, instead of using `case object`s which extend a common trait for the invalid results (as in the example), I'd like to use `case class`es (which extend a common trait) so I can include contextual information in the case of failure.  Can this be done as simply as calling all the validation methods (putting the results in a tuple), as in the `validateForm` example, and calling `mapN`?  I'm getting conflicting errors from Intellij (from IntelliJ, it's telling me the expected and actual parameters to `mapN` are the same (though it is still marking it as an error); when running `sbt` on the command line, it doesn't resolve the `mapN` method.  I'm using Scala 2.12.8 and cats 2.0.0-M1.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/6cf51c3563dba62307a2a256eeb4ebb5

---

"IntelliJ errors" are irrelevant.

Regarding "sbt errors", in order to make `mapN` work, check that you have

```
import cats.syntax.apply._
```

If this still doesn't work for you provide your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I do have `cats.syntax.apply._` imported; the error I'm getting from sbt after calling all the validation methods (with the results in a tuple) is `possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value mapN'?`.  I will submit an MCVE as soon as I have a chance.  Thanks for replying!

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to reply, but here is a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tperrigo/adc9dc4d3775ff235da47b19e2e20dd6) which recreates the compile error I've been experiencing (`ValidationExample.scala:47:35: value mapN is not a member of (ValidatorNec.this.ValidationResult[java.time.LocalDateTime], ValidatorNec.this.ValidationResult[Double])
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value mapN'?`)

Comment: @TimothyPerrigo 
If you imported `cats.implicits._` you shouldn't import `cats.syntax.apply._`, otherwise you make ambiguity. If you remove the import the error is `type mismatch;
 found   : App.Reading.type
 required: (java.time.LocalDateTime, Double) => App.Reading`. So for some reason compiler doesn't recognize `Reading` as a function.

Comment: @TimothyPerrigo  If you replace `Reading` with `Reading(_,_)` you'll have `type mismatch;
 found   : java.time.LocalDateTime
 required: java.time.LocalDate` and you'll see that your definition of case class `Reading` is incorrect.

Comment: @TimothyPerrigo https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/6cf51c3563dba62307a2a256eeb4ebb5

Comment: Oh man...I apologize for missing something so simple!  Thanks for your help!